# Change the Process priority of a device driver

Tags: process, io

I have a specific device driver which is used to do Motion Control over the parallel port on my machine.

I'm told that the issues I'm having are caused by other windows processes taking away it's CPU time.

So i want to change the priority fo the thread for this device driver (Mach3.sys) to realtime.

But I can't find it in the Process list in task manager.

Does anyone know how to get it show up, to alter it's priority in another way, or
if it's run inside another process what exactly that is.
, so that I can alter it's priority.

Comment: Not a programming question. You will get a much better result on ServerFault.com.

Comment: Page 5-39 of http://www.machsupport.com/docs/Mach3Mill_Install_Config.pdf suggests it may be called "Mach3.exe". You could presumably also ask their tech support. When you bring up task manager, don't forget to press on the "Show processes from all users" button, in case the process is running as a system service instead of as you.